# 別ドメインのログインユーザーのメールアドレスを取得する方法

Tags: google-apps-script

ウエブアプリケーションとして公開
次のユーザーとしてアプリケーションを実行:ウエブアプリケーションにアクセスしているユーザー
アプリケーションにアクセスできるユーザー：全員

とスクリプトを設定している場合

Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

だとスクリプトのオーナーと違うドメインのログインユーザーのメールアドレスを取得できません

この場合に、ログインユーザーのメールアドレスを取得する方法は何かないのでしょうか？

Answer (score -2):

最近はできるようになりましたね。試してみてください。

Comment: 解決したなら承認をして頂けるとありがたいです。どのような方法でできるのかを詳しく書いたら良い回答になると思います。